# What does the "Appoiintment with the Street of Peace" Monopoly chance card mean?

Tags: monopoly

Can anyone please help me with this card, it is so confusing.

[image: Chance card bearing "Appointment with the street of peace"]

Comment: What version/edition of Monopoly do you have; is it in a non-English language?

Comment: Appoiintment with two "i"s is non-standard English, for sure.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson Can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 69):

This card appears to be poorly translated into English from a French version of the game. In the original English, it would be "Advance token to Boardwalk", so you simply move you token forward until you get to Boardwalk, and then deal with it normally (either pay rent, or purchase it, etc).

In the official French version, the card says "Rendez-vous à la Rue de la Paix". The Boardwalk space is called "Rue de la Paix", which translates to "Street of Peace". And "Rendez-vous" is literally "go to", but generally translated as "Appointment" because that's also how it is used.

Comment: Not sure what the current wording is, but in the 1970s this card in American sets read "Take a walk on Boardwalk." along with an admonition to follow usual rules once there ("If it is unowned, you may buy it." or something of the sort).

Comment: Interestingly it has a copyright from Hasbro, so it's not some random knock-off.

Comment: I think the translation of appointment might stem from a mistranslation of "rendez-vous (à)" the French imperative for "present yourself (at)". As a noun "rendezvous" also means appointment.

Comment: @Barmar My thought is it could be a counterfeit copy.

Comment: Next thing you'll tell me is that Monopoly money isn't legal tender.

Comment: Note that it says *appo**ii**ntment*, there's an extra `i` there, which lends further credence to your bad translation theory. What a shoddy piece of work!

Comment: My hovercraft is full of eels.

Comment: @QueensKnight It's indeed the formulation used in French Monopoly, at least on my (pre-euro) edition. This card reads "Rendez-vous à la Rue de la Paix".

Comment: @AmiralPatate Thanks, I've added that info to the answer!

Comment: @Barmar: Typing _© Copyright, 2003 Hasbro_ is pretty easy to do.  So is saying _Monopoly™ is a trademark of Hasbro, Inc._.

Comment: I will not buy this community chest, it is scratched.